Problem with the triggering the 555 monostable trigger
I am currently making a dual speed dc motor circuit that is controlled by 555 timers. My goal is to have DC motor full speed below 2V and between 2-3V, the DC motor spins half-speed using PWM from 555 timer with a 15 second period (Via monostable 555 timer). Anything above 3V the motor is turned off. I made the circuit in multisim and it works perfectly fine. However when I made it physically there were issues with my trigger of the monostable 555 timer.
Problem: The 555 monostable is not triggering when I go from above 3V into the 2-3V range where the monostable triggers causes astable 555 timer to make PWM 50%. It works fine when I go from below 2V into 2-3V. That portion triggers perfectly fine and turns motor off after 15 seconds. How do i fix this triggering problem?

I will link my multisim here: https://www.multisim.com/content/kbWYuP36VDNgLoemzdSPe2/dual-speed-motor-555-timer-circuit/

What is your question?

Comparators can have hysteresis, which means they may not switch cleanly between states. This could cause the monostable 555 timer to miss the trigger when transitioning from above 3V to the 2-3V range.

I can virtually guarantee that anything composed of two 555s will be much easier to build in all: components, circult complexity, failure modes, and component tolerances, when replaced with a single microcontroller. These things are cheap, and really not that hard to program anymore. In your case, motor control is exactly the thing that microcontrollers have been optimized (and cost optimized!) for, for decades. An Arduino compatible based an an STM32L01 costs < 4€ in quantities of 1. The fact that it works with a single decoupling capacitor and has an ADC as well as a PWM unit means…

that of the ca 25 components of your schematic, not counting the different power supplies you wouldn't need anymore, you could throw away all, and replace them with, full count: 2× resistors to bring the input signal into the ADC range, if necessary at all, 1 gate resistor, 1 MOSFET, 1 decoupling capacitor and 1 microcontroller. For good measure, you'd add a pair of diodes to the input (in normally blocking direction  to ground and microcontroller supply voltage) to make it safer agains over- and undervoltages, and a pull-down to the n-channel MOSFET gate to have a defined off-state.

@VoltageSpike I am wondering how i can fix the triggering from above 3 volts into 2-3V since it is not triggering my 555 timers.

@MarcusMüller I also would love to use a microcontroller but for this project I am not allowed to use a microcontroller

@AnsonChow so this is homework? please tag as [tag:homework] then! Also, why is there the [tag:arduino] tag, then? are there other constraints you forget to mention?
